# Very slow sql insert query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

i have postgresql function that works very slow. There is problem with one of the queries. Is there any way to optimize it? Indexes I made didn`t help much.

```
INSERT INTO aa_c_axis_doc_oper 
SELECT a.pool_id, 
       l.lane_id, 
       a.axis_id, 
       l.id AS src_row_id, 
       a.running_sum_abs, 
       a.running_sum_abs_begin_max, 
       l.program_id 
FROM   aa_oper_axis AS a 
       INNER JOIN aa_src1 AS l 
               ON a.pool_id = l.pool_id 
WHERE  l.running_sum_abs_begin <= a.running_sum_abs_begin_max 
       AND a.running_sum_abs <= l.running_sum_abs
```

**Explain**

```
Insert on aa_c_axis_doc_oper  (cost=0.00..19727005.41 rows=345535083 width=84) (actual time=5428290.637..5428290.637 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..19727005.41 rows=345535083 width=84) (actual time=235.809..5348024.371 rows=9954308 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on aa_oper_axis a  (cost=0.00..50396.63 rows=6085633 width=72) (actual time=0.040..3351.155 rows=6012431 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using aa_src1_pool_id_running_sum_abs_begin_running_sum_abs_idx on aa_src1 l  (cost=0.00..2.75 rows=57 width=34) (actual time=0.881..0.887 rows=2 loops=6012431)
              Index Cond: ((pool_id = a.pool_id) AND (running_sum_abs_begin <= a.running_sum_abs_begin_max) AND (a.running_sum_abs <= running_sum_abs))
Total runtime: 5428290.775 ms
```

Comment: This is probably will get more attention [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Alexander ... but you can flag it for migration. Madbw, there is no need to re-post elsewhere.

Comment: @CraigRinger I didn't know that, thank you. And, actually, that was only suggestion, I'm not sure.

Comment: Usually order of tables in join doesn't matter but just curious what if to change JOIN order to `FROM aa_src1 as l INNER JOIN aa_oper_axis as a`

Comment: Your inner loop retrieves 2*6M tuples and retains 9M tuples. The outer query inserts 0 rows. I'd say you have an (almost) cartesian join in your inner loop. Please check the join condition. (should '<' in fact be '>' ???)

Comment: @joop the insert node of an "explain analyze" always reports 0 actual rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to figure out whether the SELECT or INSERT is the bottleeneck. If the SELECT is slow try to add indexes to the fields used in WHERE (like running_sum_abs_begin ). If the insert is sow check whether you have e.g. insert trigger on the aa_c_axis_doc_oper table.

If there are a lot of records to be inserted it could be single transaction problem. You should try to split the insert into multiple smaller transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Are there indexes or triggers on aa_c_axis_doc_oper? If so, try disabling them temporarily.

Are there indexes for pool_id on aa_oper_axis and aa_src1? If not, try adding them.

Comment: aa_src1 have index (pool_id, running_sum_abs_begin ASC, running_sum_abs ASC);
aa_oper_axis and aa_src1 have index (pool_id, running_sum_abs ASC, running_sum_abs_begin_max ASC);
aa_c_axis_doc_oper have one index. I`ll try to disable it.
All 3 are temp tables without triggers.

Comment: You might want to try an index on aa_oper_axis and aa_src1 for pool_id only - unique if possible